# PHP / MYSQL + while repetition

Tags: php

I'm trying to display `ul>li` list using PHP while loop and MYSQL.
My database 'company' has table 'news' with 2 columns ' id & content'.

The while loop works correctly it is returning two `'li'` = as there are two rows in the table.

But, instate of data from the table something like this `$indx." - ".$ID." ".$CONTENT."` is inserted in each 'li'.

My `while` loop:

```
    $readNews_SQLselect = "SELECT  ";
    $readNews_SQLselect .= "id, content ";  // rows names
    $readNews_SQLselect .= "FROM ";
    $readNews_SQLselect .= "news ";         // table name


    $readNews_SQLselect_Query = mysql_query($readNews_SQLselect);   

    $indx = 1;  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($readNews_SQLselect_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $ID = $row['id'];
        $CONTENT = $row['content'];



        echo '<li>$indx." - ".$ID." ".$CONTENT."</li>';

        $indx++;

    }

    mysql_free_result($readNews_SQLselect_Query);
```

I'm 99% sure is the syntax issue with `echo '<li>$indx." - ".$ID." ".$CONTENT."</li>';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
'<li>$indx." - ".$ID." ".$CONTENT."</li>';
```

with:

```
'<li>'. $indx .' - ' . $ID .' ' . $CONTENT . '</li>';
```

**EDIT 1**

or with:

```
"<li>$indx - $ID $CONTENT</li>";
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't substitute variables in single quoted strings.

```
echo "<li>$indx - $ID $CONTENT</li>";
```

Comment: check first quote (or last) $-)